# Does parsley.js support positive feedback valid messages?

Tags: validation, parsley.js

Does *parsley.js* support positive feedback valid messages?

For example, `"Password looks good."` for a password type field.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very simple & straight forward, You just have to listen to success events from your parsley html element and update your DOM element accordingly, I mean show/hide success message 
(Here I'm assuming that you are capable of adding your own div/span in html and also for displaying it through JS code while listing to proper event).

Refer: [Parsley Event Documentation](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#events)